# VB.Net InputBox validation negative number

Tags: vb.net, validation, negative-number, inputbox

I'm working on a program for a user to input a number in an InputBox. I could write the codes to validate the input value is numeric, but I couldn't came up with a procedure to validate the negative number from InputBox.

```
        Dim UserInput As String = ""
        Dim UserInputAsNumber As Integer
        Dim SumofTotal As Integer

        'to display InputBox
        UserInput = (InputBox("Enter a positive number", "Input Needed"))

        'to capture userinput is not numeric value
        While (Not IsNumeric(UserInput))
            UserInput = (InputBox("Enter a positive number", "Input Needed"))
        End While

        'if userinput is number, convert the value to numeric variable
        UserInputAsNumber = CInt(UserInput)

        If (UserInputAsNumber <= 0) Then
            UserInput = (InputBox("Enter a positive number", "Input Needed"))
        Else
            SumofTotal = CInt(((UserInputAsNumber * (UserInputAsNumber + 1)) / 2))
            'calculation
        End If

        MessageBox.Show("The sum is " & CStr(SumofTotal))
    End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried this  `UserInput < 0`? I'm not sure if it'll work...

Comment: No~ doesn't work. The program required the user to enter a positive number, and do the calculation from there.

Comment: I think it'll not work because of `Dim UserInputAsNumber As Integer` doesn't have a value... you just declared a variable... did you assign any value to that variable?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a textbox there. assign your textbox to the variable that you've created.. somewhat like this `Dim UserInputAsNumber As Integer = textbox1.text`

Comment: Yes, I did: UserInputAsNumber = CInt(UserInput)

Comment: your ` Dim UserInput As String = ""`... doesn't have a value.

Comment: because I reserved for inputbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your code until you get a valid positive integer. You can simplify things by using Integer.TryParse to validate the string and convert it to an integer (invalid strings will convert to zero).

```
Private Sub btnEnterNumbers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterNumbers.Click
    Dim UserInput As String = ""
    Dim UserInputAsNumber As Integer
    Dim SumofTotal As Integer

    Do While UserInputAsNumber <= 0
        'to display InputBox
        UserInput = (InputBox("Enter a positive integer value", "Input Needed", "10"))

        'convert to integer, will be zero if not valid integer
        Integer.TryParse(UserInput, UserInputAsNumber)
    Loop

    '    Gauss formula to calculate the total of a sequence of numbers from userinput
    SumofTotal = CInt(UserInputAsNumber * (UserInputAsNumber + 1) / 2)

    MessageBox.Show("The sum of the numbers 1 through " & CStr(UserInputAsNumber) & " is " & CStr(SumofTotal))
End Sub
```